# Base64 Encript/Decript (C++ Builder XE)

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm need encrypt a content of strings in C++ Builder XE and found this code on the internet:

```
AnsiString Base64Encode(AnsiString slToEnc)
      {
        //The Base64 Table
        const char Base64Table[64]=
          "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        char * buftoenc = slToEnc.c_str();
        int bufsize = slToEnc.Length() + 1;
        char * encbuf = new char[slToEnc.Length() * 5];
        encbuf[0] = '\0';  int ilStrLen = -1;
        int i=0; int b64byte[5];
        unsigned char *buftemp;
        AnsiString slRetVal = EmptyStr;
        buftemp=(unsigned char *)malloc(bufsize+2);
        strcpy(buftemp,buftoenc);

        if (fmod(bufsize,3)==1)
        {
          buftemp[bufsize]='\0';
          buftemp[bufsize+1]='\0';
        }

        if (fmod(bufsize,3)==2)buftemp[bufsize]='\0';

        while (i<bufsize)
        {
          b64byte[0]=buftemp[i]>>2;
          b64byte[1]=((buftemp[i]&3)<<4)|(buftemp[i+1]>>4);
          b64byte[2]=((buftemp[i+1]&0x0F)<<2)|(buftemp[i+2]>>6);
          b64byte[3]=buftemp[i+2]&0x3F;
          encbuf[i+(i/3)]=Base64Table[b64byte[0]];
          encbuf[i+(i/3)+1]=Base64Table[b64byte[1]];
          encbuf[i+(i/3)+2]=Base64Table[b64byte[2]];
          encbuf[i+(i/3)+3]=Base64Table[b64byte[3]];
          i+=3;
        }

        free(buftemp);

        if (fmod(bufsize,3)==0) ilStrLen = bufsize*8/6;
        else if (fmod(bufsize,3)==1) ilStrLen = ((bufsize+2)*8/6)-2;
        else if (fmod(bufsize,3)==2) ilStrLen = ((bufsize+1)*8/6)-1;
        else ilStrLen = -1;

        if(ilStrLen> 0) slRetVal = AnsiString(encbuf).SubString(1, ilStrLen);
        if(encbuf != NULL) { delete encbuf; encbuf = NULL; }

        return slRetVal;
      }

// Calling function in a button component =>

Base64Encode(Memo1->Text);
```

But it generates a small erro on compilation making reference to ambiguity between the function  std::fmod(double, double)  being in this source code and the same function of `math.h` library.

Some suggestion?

Comment: You should be able to just throw a `std::` to resolve the ambiguity.  I would suggest going with a slightly cleaner algorithm that uses more std library and doesn't require the use of `malloc` `new` `free` and `delete`. Take a look at [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64#C.2B.2B](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64#C.2B.2B) that is the encode algorithm, the decode is further down the page.  You should be able to adapt that to your code fairly easily.

Comment: @pstrjds  put the comment as an answer and I'll give you some points

Comment: I tested this same code in BCB 6.0, and not show any error on compilation, but this function don't work. I'm now wanting convert a code from Delphi to C++ Builder XE, I found this simple algorithm  => http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1691&lngWId=7 but I have question about how stay converted the functions "Chr" and "Ord" respectively in C++ Builder.

Comment: @LuizEduardo - In general you should not roll your own crypto code.  If you need encryption in C++ I would recommend a well tested library like [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). I would avoid trying to port that Delphi code.  If you are really just trying to add a minimal amount of obfuscation to some data, just XOR each byte with 42, or for a slightly higher level of obfuscation, XOR each byte with a hard coded array of bytes (i.e. byte 1 of the string with byte 1 of the array, byte 2 with 2 and when you hit the end of the hard coded array, you start over at byte 1).

Comment: @pstrjds: For Base64, that should be OK, it's not truly _encryption_ anyway, merely an encoding scheme that fits in fewer bits per character (but uses more characters).

Comment: @Damon - I wasn't talking about the Base64 question, I was responding to the OP's comment with a link to a Delphi script that he wanted to port that is supposed to be an "encryption" algorithm. The OP says he wanted to use that now as well.

Comment: @pstrjds: Oh I see, missed that one, sorry.

Comment: @Damon - no worries :)  I kind of wish I knew what the ultimate goal was for the code as that could lead to a better suggestion as to how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the ambiguity you need to specify the namespace for the `fmod` function. Just change the line:

```
if (fmod(bufsize,3)==1)
```

to:

```
if (std::fmod(bufsize,3)==1)
```

and it should compile for you.

Comment: The code snippet above don't resolved about the compilation, but thank you. No more worry, I not go use this code, he not encript absolutely nothing :D, tested for me in BCB6 (that compiled fine). Can close this thread!

Comment: I just looked at your code again, did you change all references to `fmod` to `std::fmod`?  As far as closing the question. You are able to remove it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

My version is a simple fast encoder (decoder) of base64 for C++ Builder.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeString __fastcall TExample::Base64Encode(void *data,int length)
{
 if (length<=0) return L"";
 static const char set[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
 unsigned char *in=(unsigned char*)data;
 char *pos,*out=pos=new char[((length-1)/3+1)<<2];
 while ((length-=3)>=0)
 {
  pos[0]=set[in[0]>>2];
  pos[1]=set[((in[0]&0x03)<<4)|(in[1]>>4)];
  pos[2]=set[((in[1]&0x0F)<<2)|(in[2]>>6)];
  pos[3]=set[in[2]&0x3F];
  pos+=4;
  in+=3;
 };
 if ((length&2)!=0)
 {
  pos[0]=set[in[0]>>2];
  if ((length&1)!=0)
  {
   pos[1]=set[((in[0]&0x03)<<4)|(in[1]>>4)];
   pos[2]=set[(in[1]&0x0F)<<2];
  }
  else
  {
   pos[1]=set[(in[0]&0x03)<<4];
   pos[2]='=';
  };
  pos[3]='=';
  pos+=4;
 };
 UnicodeString code=UnicodeString(out,pos-out);
 delete[] out;
 return code;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int __fastcall TExample::Base64Decode(const UnicodeString &code,unsigned char **data)
{
 int length;
 if (((length=code.Length())==0)||((length&3)!=0)) return 0;
 wchar_t *str=code.c_str();
 unsigned char *pos,*out=pos=new unsigned char[(length>>2)*3];
 while (*str!=0)
 {
  length=-1;
  int shift=18,bits=0;
  do
  {
   wchar_t s=str[++length];
   if ((s>=L'A')&&(s<=L'Z')) bits|=(s-L'A')<<shift;
   else if ((s>=L'a')&&(s<=L'z')) bits|=(s-(L'a'-26))<<shift;
   else if (((s>=L'0')&&(s<=L'9'))) bits|=(s-(L'0'-52))<<shift;
   else if (s==L'+') bits|=62<<shift;
   else if (s==L'/') bits|=63<<shift;
   else if (s==L'=')
   {
    length--;
    break;
   }
   else
   {
    delete[] out;
    return 0;
   };
  }
  while ((shift-=6)>=0);
  pos[0]=bits>>16;
  pos[1]=bits>>8;
  pos[2]=bits;
  pos+=length;
  str+=4;
 };
 *data=out;
 return pos-out;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding

```
TBase64Encoding* enc = new TBase64Encoding();
UnicodeString decoded = enc->Decode(encoded);
delete enc;

TBase64Encoding* enc = new TBase64Encoding();
UnicodeString encoded = enc->Encode(whatever);
delete enc;
```